# Azure File Storage, using SAS

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files, azure-sas

I am confused about using Azure File Storage and SAS.  I thought the point of a SAS was to be able to have access to a resource without needing the account key.

I am looking to do a simple file upload, and when looking into this method, there are examples provided but the first thing they all do is create a CloudStorageAccount by .Parse on the connection string, which is the account key.

Can anyone point to a sample project or sample code which uploads a file to an Azure File Storage account, but doesn't use the account Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to construct a `CloudFile` object:

```
var cloudFile = new CloudFile(new Uri(fileUri), new StorageCredentials(sasToken));
```

Comment: That does work, but maybe you can answer one other question for me...the app I'm working on has a mandate not to store any account key info in any config files.  The app needs to write files to storage.  In code, is there a way to generate the uri+sas token given that the base uri and container name can be stored as app settings?  so I could construct the full uri if I'm able to generate a short-lived sasToken in code...is that possible?

Comment: @Mike. That's not possible, SAS is generated **with storage account key**. Thus, you'll need to get account key at first somehow. If you're not able to save it in config, you can probably try Azure Key Vault.